# I want to host Spotfire web player UI in an iframe. Can I do this with Spotfire Desktop?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I've downloaded Spotfire desktop. I can't figure out how to host the webplayer inside an iframe. Is this possible with Spotfire desktop?

Comment: Spotfire Desktop and Spotfire Web Player are different pieces of software.

Desktop allows you to create analytics files on your local machine.

Web Player requires Spotfire Server to operate, and allows access to the Spotfire Server library via a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The following link 
http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Tasks/IntegratingWithWebPlayer.aspx
leads to the Tibco Spotfire documentation that describes how to embed Spotfire within the Iframe.

That operation does NOT have anything directly related to the Spotfire desktop.
You use desktop to create Dashboards and you do actions from the link above to embed the dashboards inside the Iframe.